# Sending message to client(JSF view ) from server(websocket) with ejb timer service

Tags: jsf, ejb, java-websocket

I want to know how to send a message from the server (using websocket) to the clientside (JSF 2.2) with EJB 3.2 Timer Service (every 10 seconds). Please explain using Java EE 7 API.

Comment: What is 'plain java ee 7 api'? Not using Omnifaces?

Comment: when i googled, i found some solutions but they are using java ee 8 version.

Comment: I never asked about Java EE 8, I asked about Omnifaces

Comment: Now  I have tried omnifaces and it's ok now bro .Thank you.

Comment: Great... Omnifaces is good for much more than this... a.o Creating messages